# Running black only on committed python files

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I am just trying to use `precommit` as a git hook on my python project. What I want to do is to run black only on the committed files. I am also running black through poetry.

At the moment my config looks like:

```
fail_fast: true
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: system
        name: Black
        entry: poetry run black .
        pass_filenames: false
        language: system
```

This, of course, runs black on the whole project structure and this is not what I want.

Is it possible to just run black on the committed files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not constrained by using `poetry`, you can use the following that will solve your purpose:

```yaml
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.6.0
    hooks:
      - id: black
        language_version: python3.9 # Change this with your python version
        args:
          - --target-version=py39 # Change this with your python version
```

This will respect any and all settings you may have defined in `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: hmmmmm but will this run black only on committed files?

Comment: this is indeed the supported way to run `black` through pre-commit - the pre-commit author

Comment: Yes @Luca, it will run black only on the committed files.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
fail_fast: true
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: black
        name: Black
        entry: poetry run black
        language: system
        types: [file, python]
        stages: [commit]
```

Explanation:

1. Remove `pass_filenames: false` to use the default `true`.
2. Remove `.` from the `poetry run black` command. When pre-commit runs it will append the file names to the end. I.e: `poetry run black file1 file2 file3`
3. Specify the file types.
4. Optional: specify the stage.